# How do questions on the "Tour" page get chosen?

Tags: support, tour

Every SE site has a [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) page. This page exhibits various *actual* Q&A from the site.

On Lifehacks.SE, [the tour](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour) uses one of my questions. Was this manually selected by somebody on the SE Community Team, or automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are selected automatically, although the selection can be overridden by moderators - once a question becomes eligible to be on the tour page, the site moderators can select it.

The criteria (beyond score - ensuring it is a *good* question) are mostly about how it will display on the tour page - things like limited set of/no HTML elements and how short it and some of the answers are.

Your question met all the criteria and was selected automatically.

Comment: Maybe worth merging this question with the dupe to have both answers in the same place? Both look good. :)